# Operatorcoloring plugin script doesn't work after switching colorscheme

Tags: vim

In vim I've written a plugin in order to enable operator coloring,

**file: ~/.vim/sources/operatorColoring.vim**

```
if has('autocmd')
    autocmd BufRead,VimEnter * syn match parens /[(){}]/ | hi parens ctermfg=082
    autocmd BufRead,VimEnter * syn match sqparens /[\[\]]/ | hi sqparens ctermfg=087
    autocmd BufRead,VimEnter * syn match operatorsA /[=+%&*^;<>-]/ | hi operatorsA ctermfg=063
    autocmd BufRead,VimEnter * syn match operatorsB /[,.;!]/ | hi operatorsB ctermfg=063
    autocmd BufRead,VimEnter * syn match operatorsC /[:]/ | hi operatorsC ctermfg=196
endif
```

I enable this, depending on the file type. For example for python:

**file: ~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim**

```
source ~/.vim/sources/operatorColoring.vim
```

This principle works perfect, however it breaks when I switch the colorscheme by issuing the command `:colorscheme mycolorschme`

I believe filetype plugins are loaded automatically when a colorscheme is switched. when I issue the command `:filetype` the output is:

`filetype detection:ON plugin:ON indent:ON`

Just in case, I've also tried to issue the command `filetype=python`, still operator-coloring doesnt work. I've also tried to manually source the operatorColoring script by issuing the command `source ~/.vim/sources/operatorColoring.vim`, nothing happens when I do this. I'm a bit lost here, hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for this behaviour, simply typing `:e` will tell vim to reload all buffer-specific files (more info [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reload_your_filetype/syntax_plugin)), hence in this use case it will reload the operatorColoring script which solves the problem.